# Why do I get this strange error when using GPIO on RaspberyPI?

Tags: raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi 4B with 32 bit Raspberry Pi OS Full.
Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Mathematica for Raspberry Pi 13.1

Command line control of GPIO work as expected.
In Mathematica `DeviceWrite["GPIO", 17 -> 1]` gives this weird error and the GPIO pin does not turn on.
[image]
I only get that error the first time I run the command after starting the kernel. After that, it just returns `17->1` but it still doesn't turn the pin on.

`FindDevices["GPIO"]` returns

[image]

`Run["sudo raspi-gpio set 17 dl"]` and `Run["sudo raspi-gpio set 17 dh"]` both work fine.